# Spring Boot 3.0.0, @Value annotated field is not being updated with the latest value from the Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-3

Trying Spring Cloud Config to externalize my application's configuration, but not able to update @value at runtime.

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apiService")
public class DemoApiController {


@Value("${scheduledTaskCronExpression}")
private String scheduledTaskCronExpression;

@GetMapping("getCurrentCronExpression")
  public String getScheduledTaskCronExpression() {
        return scheduledTaskCronExpression;
 }
```

Central Config Application  - application.properties

```
spring.application.name=CentralConfig
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=local,development,production
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/XXX
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=MyApiService
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=XXX
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=XXX
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
management.security.enabled=false
health.config.enabled=false
```

MyApiService - application.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.application.name=MyApiService
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888/ 
spring.profiles.active=development
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.name=MyApiService
```

Current Value `scheduledTaskCronExpression=0 * * * * *` at github repo-MyApiService.properties.

Logs :-

1. On starting First Time, its working fine.

   ```
   o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at : 
   http://localhost:8888
   o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Located environment: 
   name=MyApiService, profiles=[default], label=main, 
   version=0590378f2e3f40de5ebeaa7985d4f1a1eb9d0fc4, state=null
   o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: 
   [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource 
   {name='bootstrapProperties- 
   https://github.com/XXX/MyApiService.properties'}]
   c.k.D.DataSyncApplication- The following 1 profile is active: "development"
   ```
2. After updating value of  `scheduledTaskCronExpression=0 */2 * * * *` at git repo and triggering `http://localhost:8082/actuator/refresh`, getting response -

   [
   "config.client.version"
   ]

and **`@Value("${scheduledTaskCronExpression}")` not getting updated at runtime**, below are the logs generated on actuator/refresh

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet    - POST "/actuator/refresh", parameters={}
o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - Devtools property defaults active! Set 
'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at : 
http://localhost:8888
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate          - HTTP GET http://localhost:8888/application/development
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate          - Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate          - Response 200 OK
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate          - Reading to 
[org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment]
o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Located environment: name=application, 
profiles=[development], label=null, version=f8b98f89c9212b1f0f5f53605a4b946aec47f40f, 
state=null
o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: 
[BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}]
o.s.boot.SpringApplication           - The following 1 profile is active: "development"
o.s.boot.SpringApplication           - Started application in 1.894 seconds (process running 
for 1687.615)
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Using 'application/vnd.spring- 
boot.actuator.v3+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/vnd.spring- 
boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json]
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Writing [[config.client.version]]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet    - Completed 200 OK
```

Comment: Do you have bootstrap enabled as well?

Comment: @spencergibb - No its not enabled. Should I enable it?

Comment: with bootstrap, its working. Thanks @spencergibb

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) instead if you want to use the live reload triggered by the config server. An additional benefit of configuration properties is that they are type-safe.